# CMake for PostgreSQL in CLion 1.2 Windows 10

Tags: postgresql, cmake, g++, mingw, clion

Unable to build C++ file with PostgreSQL in CLion 1.2 EAP.

CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(PostgreSQLTest)

find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
set(PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS, "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\include")
include_directories (${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SOURCES main.cpp)
add_executable(PostgreSQLTest ${SOURCES})
set(PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES, "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\lib")
target_link_libraries(PostgreSQLTest ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp)
```

Build messages:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 142.4859.12\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\darin\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\f846c544\f846c544\Debug --target PostgreSQLTest -- -j 8
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/darin/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/f846c544/f846c544/Debug
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable PostgreSQLTest.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibpq
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [PostgreSQLTest.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'PostgreSQLTest.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'PostgreSQLTest' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [PostgreSQLTest] Error 2
```

Does anyone have experience with this build?

**EDIT AFTER APPLYING CHANGES FROM COMMENT 2015-09-21**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(PostgreSQLTest)

set(PostgreSQL_ROOT, "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4")
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)
add_executable(PostgreSQLTest ${SOURCES})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp)
```

Errors:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 142.4859.12\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\darin\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\f846c544\f846c544\Debug --target PostgreSQLTest -- -j 8
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\Users\darin\ClionProjects\PostgreSQLTest\main.cpp:2:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
#include "libpq-fe.h"
                   ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'PostgreSQLTest' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [PostgreSQLTest] Error 2
```

I have confirmed that libpq-fh.h does exist in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\include, so there must still be something incorrect in my Cmake file that's preventing the building.

Am I missing a `target_link_libraries()` that's required to build?

**EDIT 2 AFTER APPLYING RECOMMENDED CHANGES**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

project(PostgreSQLTest)

set(PostgreSQL_ROOT "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4")
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)
add_executable(PostgreSQLTest ${SOURCES})

set(PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\lib")
target_link_libraries(PostgreSQLTest ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})


set(SOURCE_FILES
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp)
```

ERRORS:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 142.4859.12\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\darin\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\f846c544\f846c544\Debug --target all -- -j 8
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj
C:\Users\darin\ClionProjects\PostgreSQLTest\main.cpp:2:22: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
#include "libpq-fe.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir\build.make:61: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I made the recommended changes, tried several different orders for the compilation, and it's still failing.

Any ideas?

*EDITS TO MAKE AFTER COMMENT ON 2015-10-05*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(PostgreSQLTest)

# For *modify* CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, this should come after project() call.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Next line is not required, without it given path will be checked too.
#set(PostgreSQL_ROOT "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PostgreSQL\\9.4")
#set(PostgreSQL ROOT "C:\\MinGW\\compiledLibs\\psql\\postgresql-9.6devel\\tmp_install\\usr\\local\\pgsql")

set(PostgreSQL ROOT "C:\\MinGW\\msys\\1.0\\local\\pgsql")
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
message("PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS}")

# Now variables PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS, PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES are set. Just use them.
include_directories (${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCES main.cpp)
add_executable(PostgreSQLTest ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(PostgreSQLTest ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

set(SOURCE_FILES
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp)
```

I don't find anything that indicates the posgres library used.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 142.4859.12\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\darin\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\f846c544\f846c544\Debug --target all -- -j 8
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable PostgreSQLTest.exe
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z9CloseConnP7pg_conn':
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `PQfinish'
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z9ConnectDBv':
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `PQstatus'
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z19CreateEmployeeTableP7pg_conn':
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:39: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:41: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `PQclear'
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z17InsertEmployeeRecP7pg_connPKcS2_':
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:66: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:68: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:71: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:78: undefined reference to `PQclear'
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z16FetchEmployeeRecP7pg_conn':
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:88: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:90: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:93: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:98: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:101: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:102: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:105: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:110: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:112: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:114: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:117: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:122: undefined reference to `PQnfields'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:128: undefined reference to `PQfname'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:135: undefined reference to `PQgetvalue'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:132: undefined reference to `PQntuples'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:139: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:142: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:143: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:146: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:149: undefined reference to `PQclear'
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z20RemoveAllEmployeeRecP7pg_conn':
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:156: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:158: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:161: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:168: undefined reference to `PQclear'
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Z17DropEmployeeTableP7pg_conn':
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:175: undefined reference to `PQexec'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:177: undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:180: undefined reference to `PQclear'
C:/Users/darin/ClionProjects/PostgreSQLTest/main.cpp:187: undefined reference to `PQclear'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\PostgreSQLTest.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'PostgreSQLTest.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [PostgreSQLTest.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/PostgreSQLTest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: 1. If you want to adjust `find_package()` behaviour, you should set variables **before** it. 2. Variable `PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES` should contain list of **full paths** of libraries' files. But you set it to directory. Instead, you should set `PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS`. 3. Instead of setting several path variables for PostgreSQL, it is better to set root variable `PostgreSQL_ROOT` to `C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4`. Again, this should be done **before** `find_package` call.

Comment: Your reply was helpful, but I'm still unable to build. It would be helpful if you would post your complete solution as the answer.

Comment: Your original `target_link_libraries()` call was right, and it is really needed. Also, you incorrectly use `,` in `set(PostgreSQL_ROOT ...)` command: cmake uses space as delimiter between command's arguments. Also, it is better to issue `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ...)` command before first `add_executable()` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, still won't build with recommended changes. Other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(PostgreSQLTest)

# For *modify* CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, this should come after project() call.
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Next line is not required, without it given path will be checked too.
set(PostgreSQL_ROOT "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4")
find_package(PostgreSQL REQUIRED)
# Now variables PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS, PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES, PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS are set. Just use them.

include_directories (${PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCES main.cpp)
add_executable(PostgreSQLTest ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(PostgreSQLTest ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES})

set(SOURCE_FILES
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp)
```

Main(but not solely) purpose of `find_package(PostgreSQL)` call is to set variables `PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES`, `PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS` (and some others). No needs to set these variables manually afterwards, just use them.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to post this with explanations. We are getting very close, but it appears that the linker is getting stuck on this "cannot find -llibpq". I assume it's trying to link this library, but I don't know cmake well. There are several libpq.* files in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\lib. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Just found, that `PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES` variable is just `libpq`, not a full path to the library. So you need to use `link_directories` command (see updated answer).

Comment: Yes, thank you! That solved the linker issue. I believe we're on the last hurdle. None of the PostgreSQL functions are recognized. I get undefined reference to PQFinish, PQconnectdb, PQstatus, PQexec, etc... The example that I'm using is from here: http://www.askyb.com/cpp/c-postgresql-example-in-linux/.

Comment: Hmm, you use mingw for compile your project, so `PostgreSQL` itself should be compiled using mingw tools. As its installation path is under `C:\Program Files`, it seems this is not your case, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, CLion is using MinGW to compile my project. Let me research this a bit, and I'll post what I find. I don't have time right now. Once I figure this out, I will post.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response @Tsyvarev. I've been vacationing, and got distracted from this... I cannot find any postgresql packages in MinGW, so I installed the 32-bit version of postgresql and pointed to those libraries to compile the program without success. All of the postgresql function calls are still not recognized.

Comment: I found this, which is a install/compile using MinGW for windows: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Building_With_MinGW. I downloaded, compiled and installed postgresql 9.4, and verified the functionality from the command line. All works just fine. Updated the ROOT to the location of the installation:  set(PostgreSQL ROOT "C:\\MinGW\\msys\\1.0\\local\\pgsql"), but none of the PQ* functions for posgresql can be found still. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: When you set `PostgreSQL_ROOT` to you MinGW installation, is this installation correctly recognized by `find_package(PostgreSQL)`? Check(e.g., using `message()` command) that variables `PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS` and `PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS` are actually points inside MinGW installation.

Comment: I've not used the message() command before, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything. I see nothing print when I attempt to compile the project. I also posted in the JetBrains forum, but no response for two days: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/473398.

Comment: I mean placing `message("PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS}")` somewhere **after** `find_package(PostgreSQL)` call. In that case line `PostgreSQL_LIBRARY_DIRS: <value>` will be printed at configuration stage (when `cmake.exe` is executed). Path, contained in this variable should be either under your MinGW installation(if it has correctly been recognized by CMake) or under default PostgreSQL installation otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for being explicit. See edits in the question, and results. I don't see anything that tells me what directory is being used.

Comment: CLion builds CMake project in two phases: **configuration** and **build**. While *build* phase is executed every time, *configuration* phase it executed only first time and whenever you change `CMakeLists.txt` file. E.g., after you add `message()` command into `CMakeLists.txt`, only first CLion build will execute *configuration* phase, which prints given message. Futher CLion builds will skip this phase, until you change `CMakeLists.txt` again.

Comment: I tried removing the line saving, paste line then saving, then removing the line saving building, then replacing the line saving and building, and none of the four times did i see any message that showed me the directory being used. Sorry, not sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: I recently reinstalled my system, compiled postgresql via mingw avoided installing the server through the Windows installer, and the make file provided works as expected. I cannot connect to the server even with trust in pg_hba.conf, but this is a configuration issue. Cmake is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

just use this, tested on mac.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(postgres)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_custom_target(postgres COMMAND make -C ${postgres_SOURCE_DIR})
```

[cmake done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acZwj.png)